# Ignore validations on few fields according to another field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I use **jquery validation engine** to validate following form.

```
Static <input type="radio" name="mode" value="Static" data-validation-engine="validate[required] radio" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>

DHCP <input type="radio" name="mode" value="dhcp" data-validation-engine="validate[required] radio" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>

IP <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[ipv4]]" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>

Gateway <input type="text" name="gateway" id="gateway" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[ipv4]]" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>

DNS <input type="text" name="dns" id="dns" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[ipv4]]" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>
```

Normally ip/gateway/dns validate as per the rules, but I need to ignore the ip/gateway/dns validation when dhcp mode selection. (**validations needs only for static mode selection**)

In jquery script I just initialize the validateEngine as below.

```
$("#my_form").validationEngine();
```

Any idea how I can archive this task.

Comment: Have you tried using `condRequired`.
`<input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" data-validation-engine="validate[condRequired[Static],custom[ipv4]]" data-prompt-position="topRight:-70"/>`
assuming that first radio button has id `Static`

Comment: thanks for the help. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

called this function `onchange` event of radio button, if dpcp, state is `true` otherwise `false`

```
function state_change(state){
    if(state){
        $('#ip').removeAttr("data-validation-engine");
        $('#gateway').removeAttr("data-validation-engine");
        $('#dns').removeAttr("data-validation-engine");
    } else{
        $('#ip').attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required,custom[ipv4]]");
        $('#gateway').attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required,custom[ipv4]]");
        $('#dns').attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required,custom[ipv4]]");
    }
}
```